# Return a query without LiveData

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-room, android-livedata

Basically what I want to do is when I open my app It'll make a query to get a value from the database and use it.

I'm using Room and when I try not to use LiveData it tells me `Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time` , so I wonder how could I avoid using LiveData, because if I use it *(if I understood right)* I can't just pick the information from the database - I have to wait until something changes and only then I'd have access to the query results.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a simple solution.

Because I just want this query used once - on app startup, I just enabled Room database to use the main thread using the [allowMainThreadQueries()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#allowMainThreadQueries()) function.

You're welcome to post here your solution if you think it's better, it would be appreciated.